# Why can FOR not find a specified file when used to read all lines from within my batch script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a few log files that my batch script needs to be able to read and parse.

I've run into a bit of a problem, where my **FOR** loop can read most files, but cannot read a specific one. If I run in a command prompt window

```
for /f %Z in (N151204.log) do echo %Z
```

it works great, but exactly the same syntax on a different file:

```
for /f %Z in (IN151205.log) do echo %Z
```

Gives me:

> The system cannot find the file IN151205.log.

I can read file `IN151205.log` with

```
more IN151205.log
```

without a problem. So it doesn't seem to be a permissions issue, or read-locked as far as I can tell.

Why is the for loop having issues with this particular file?

Comment: Without seeing real filenames, it's impossible to say. Most likely it's because of a space in the filename and you've forgotten to use "" around it, but with made up names it's difficult to tell. When you're asking us to debug your code, it's important to include the *real code* and not something you make up on the fly.

Comment: File names have no spaces in them. They are literally one character apart - working filename is IN151204.log and not working filename is IN151205.log. The real code in the batch script would over complicate this question significantly, and unnecessarily - I've simplified the problem into the smallest and simplest form possible.

Comment: But what about the path. Does the path have spaces? Please not that in a batch-file you should use %%Z btw, not %Z like in cmd.

Comment: @Tal how do you know that other parts of your larger batch file are not causing the problem.

Comment: The path has no spaces anywhere in it. I know it's not any other part of the script causing the problem because I can replicate the problem by running that one for loop line directly in CMD, hence the usage of %Z instead of %%Z.

Comment: @Tal so knowing what we know now from the answer below can you say for certain that it was not any other part of your batch file that was not causing the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message of command **FOR** is caused by the fact that **FOR** command opens a file for reading always using [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) with `FILE_SHARE_READ` AND `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`.

The log file `IN151205.log` is obviously written at the moment by another application with having a write lock established on the file. The file access by command **FOR** fails therefore with a sharing violation because of `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`.

**MORE** has success to open the file with write lock set and outputs the lines as it really only reads the file and using a different method. **MORE** uses [CreateFileMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-createfilemappingw) using `PAGE_READWRITE` to read and output the file contents page wise which works completely different than `CreateFile` and can be used also on files currently locked by another application as mentioned in **Remarks** section with:

> It is not required, but it is recommended that files you intend to map be opened for exclusive access.

`PAGE_READWRITE` allows also read access on a file currently allowing only read access according to sharing mode.

See also the Microsoft documentations [Generic Access Rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/generic-access-rights) and [File Security and Access Rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-security-and-access-rights).

The error message output by **FOR** on access to a file fails because of a sharing violation is obviously not good as being misleading for users.

**EDIT:**

Reading a write-locked file **from within a batch file** line by line with ignoring empty lines can be done with

```
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ('more IN151205.log') do echo(%%I
```

and with

```
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ('type IN151205.log') do echo(%%I
```

Thanks [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini) and [Squashman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman) for this additional information.

Comment: Good explanation! The obvious question is: how do you know which are the specific Win-32 API functions used by each part of a Batch file?

Comment: Thanks! Any trick to read a file line by line in a batch script if the file is write-locked?

Comment: You may use: `for /f %Z in ('more IN151205.log') do echo %Z`

Comment: The specific Win-32 API functions used by a command can be find out by running just a single command from within a command prompt window and use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor) with an appropriate filter defined. For this answer I opened the file with text editor UltraEdit with having usage of a temporary file disabled resulting in opening the file with a write-lock by UltraEdit. Then I logged with Process Monitor all file accesses on this file on running __FOR__ and __MORE__ and evaluated the Process Monitor log for each command.